# Connect mongodb from Python in authorized mode

Tags: python, mongodb

I've created a user for my database in mongodb. I've tested with mongo shell to make sure that the user has proper privileges to access the database.
Now I want to use my Python program to access the database, and I use [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html). If I run mongod in unauthorized mode (without option `--auth`), the Python client works fine. However, when I use `--auth` option, the Python client doesn't work any more. In fact, it reports `unauthorized error`, which is easy to understand because I didn't change anything in the code. Here is the code to connect my `test` database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
cursor = db.restaurants.find()
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

My question is how can I change the Python code to use username/password created previously? I've looked at the client documentation but there is not information for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@server/dbname")
```

This is the normal format for telling the client where and how to connect. The way you are using (with no parameters at all) defaults to a local mongo install, on the default port, with no authentication.

Comment: Be aware that if you password contains reserved characters (like ':' or '@') you'll run into problems. As I had this issue, I created a [question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237813/how-to-escape-in-a-password-in-pymongo-connection).

Answer (score 2):

Besides [Danielle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150113/4385621) you can also use [authenticate](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#scram-sha-1-rfc-5802) method for that. Your code would look like this:

```
from pymongo 
import MongoClient 
client = MongoClient() 
db = client.test 
db.authenticate('user', 'password', mechanism=<either 'SCRAM-SHA-1' or 'MONGODB-CR', being 'MONGODB-CR' the default authentication mechanism Before MongoDB 3.0>)
cursor = db.restaurants.find() 
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```